# how to capture command line parameters after source

Tags: linux, bash

I am running linux 2.6. On bash shell, i would like to source a file. If i am in the current directory as the source file, then i can do

```
source abc.sh
```

But if i am on some other folder, i would so

```
source /path-to/abc.sh
```

I would like to capture whatever is typed after the command source on the command line in my script, So, for example, i want access to "abc.sh" and in the latter case, i want access to "/path-to/abc.sh" inside abc.sh

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the `$BASH_SOURCE` variable which contains currently processed script.

For example if `/tmp/a.sh` is:

```
echo $BASH_SOURCE
```

Then:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ . a.sh
a.sh
$ . /tmp/a.sh
/tmp/a.sh
$ . ../tmp/a.sh
../tmp/a.sh
```

You can find more on it in [info bash](http://info2html.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/info2html-demo/info2html?%28bash.info.gz%29Bash%2520Variables).